# Torque on a siezed part

Tags: torque

I have a vertical load (F) acting at a distance from the edge of the cylinder. The load is acting on the cylinder via chunk of steel sliding across the surface of the roller. The coefficient of friction between the two objects is 0.25.

The shaft is fixed at both ends. The cylinder has seized and has become a part of the shaft.

I want to know the torque and the force at the yellow point.
You must state the variables you use.

[image: Image of Problem]

I would also like an explanation of where the frictional force from the load is going.

Thanks!

Comment: You must state what you have done so far...

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (even if it isn't homework). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: I put some idea in your head, write the equilibrium equations for vertical forces  and torques, if the force cause the cylinder to deform then, you should specify if it's elastic deformation or plastic. If it's elastic, then the problem is a combination of plain strain and plain stress, and you'll have some horizontal forces there thanks to Poisson effect. Please show us what you have done.